# Save xls in cordova from alasql

Tags: android, excel, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, alasql

I have an android cordova application which is supposed to save and send xls file (via email) generated from an array. So far I have created the xls file using alasql code:

```
var data = [{a:23,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("myfile.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[data]);
```

1. In Ripple browser file is generated and downloaded successfully but on device alasql does not download any file or it does not show any action for generating a file. Where does the file generated?
2. Is it possible to force cordova-android to save the xls in a project folder?

Comment: Does it work if you provide a full path or relative path the project folder instead of only 'myfile.xlsx'?

Comment: No, doesn't work with a folder.. :(